# Scaling and Transformation of histograms

Tags: regression, estimation, curve-fitting

Basically I have some histograms of images which I want to scale and transform so that if I apply a single threshold then I would get a constant alarm rate.How can I go about doing this.Below are 2 charts which explain what is required.Assuming I use weighted linear regression how can I perform the correction by scaling and translation ? 
[image]

Comment: Please explain what the "alarm rate" of a histogram is.

Comment: The alarm rate is basically the number of pixels which will pass a threshold i set in the x axis.The histograms are basically difference images of 2 similar images .(Diff = img1-img2) and the goal is to detect anomalies.Since the diff looks semi exponential I am taking log to get linear line.Lets assume I have a target score in the x axis i want to scale and translate all the histograms to.The idea is to set a single threshold so that I would get same alarm rate (maybe one diff image is noisier than another in the same region)

Comment: Because I know what a histogram is, and I know what an image is, your statement "the histograms are basically difference images" does not make sense to me.